# Как вернуть промисс?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Можно такой небольшой вопрос. вот метод. Тут возвращается промисс

```
onClick = () => getLogin({
    permissions: 'premissions'
  })
  .then(this.handleSuccess)
  .catch(this.handleError);
```

но мне в этом методе нужно вызывать еще один метод и при этом все равно возвращать промис. то есть я добавляю явный return

```
onClick = () => {
  this.handleClick('vk');
  return getLogin({
      permissions: 'premissions'
    })
    .then(this.handleSuccess)
    .catch(this.handleError);
};
```

как правильно заменить?

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, всё и с явным return нормально. Во-вторых, если уж хочется именно синтаксически избавиться от слова `return` (либо это делается для отладки), можно поставить круглые скобки и запятую:

```js
var f = () => (console.log("f"), g());

function g() {
  console.log("g");
  return 4;
}

console.log(f());
```